# What font type is used in this site when using \$....\$?

Tags: support, mathjax

In order to replicate font in microsoft word, what font type is used in this site to make the symbols like $f$ $x$, what font type & size & Format to use in microsoft word 2013 to replicate this?

If it is MathJax_Math, then is there any equivalent or near equal?

Best Regards,

Comment: Have you looked at the [help center page on formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)?

Comment: It doesn't tell about the format (italic or not), font type or size that are used for the  text in between $

Comment: Pressing F12 and inspecting the $f$ in your post shows it's `font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;`  I don't think MS Word is going to have that.

Comment: I think the main part of the OP (regarding Word) is not a duplicate so I've added an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As comments have already mentioned, on SE sites you will either see MathJax's default [`MathJax_Math` font](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/tree/master/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX) or the  [STIX fonts](http://www.stixfonts.org/) (if you have a local copy of the regular "STIX-general" fonts; e.g., OSX ships with those).

For typesetting math in Microsoft Word, it's best to use Word's native facilities (rather than external editors) since Word's implementation actually follows Appendix G of the TeXbook (like MathJax btw). For this to work, its best to use fonts with OpenType MATH Tables; unfortunately, there are very few of those around but in this case there are obvious options:

- The [Latin Modern fonts](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/lm-math) work with Word and are quite similar to `MathJax_Math` since both are derived from Knuth's Computer Modern.
- The [STIX fonts](http://www.stixfonts.org/) also have a Word-compatible release, [STIX word](http://sourceforge.net/projects/stixfonts/files/Current%20Release/).

Comment: Wait, what -- are you saying that Word contains a TeX-compatible math engine these days?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with compatible. Word follows the layout principles developed by Knuth in the TeXbook. It does not reimplement TeX. For background and links see e.g. https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-math/2016Apr/0016.html. Still, Word's "linear input" is also quite nice, especially for TeX or asciimath users.